# AWS Dashboard query to find max,min AND count of all items above and below a threshold

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Im currently trying to create a dashboard for me to track a very critical feature.
I found out it has a xx percentile billed durations which are pretty significant.
Im trying to find out how bad it is. are most of my calls lengthy, or most of them quick?

My current query is

`filter @type = "REPORT" and @log like "some-lambda-name" | fields @requestId, @billedDuration, @log | sort by @timestamp desc | stats avg (@billedDuration), max(@billedDuration), min(@billedDuration) by bin(10m)`

I would like to add to it, also the count of all @billedDuration above 3000 and below it as lines in my graph.

The question is:
How do i do without totally refactoring my query to be something unreadable?

I saw the docs for aws queries and I had a trouble understanding if theres an easy way to do it, instead of going into mega complicated queries, which by now I feel is the case.